# Calculus stay to Real Analysis as $x$ stay to Functional Analysis

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Hi guys i had a look to book which treat the subject of Calculus (of course...) Analysis and Functional Analysis.

Is that correct to state that Calculus is more focused on "computing" while "Analysis" is more focused on theorem proving?

If yes what is the "calculus" version of Functional Analysis?

I had a glance to some book of functional analysis and most of them are pretty abstract and much focused on theorem proving, i mean... while in calculus the theory is theorem too the exercises are most focused on computation. Is there something similar for functional analysis?

I don't know all the theory of functional analysis, Rudin as instance speaks a bit of spectral theory, distributions, bounded and unbounded operator is there a "calculus" branch for this stuff?

Comment: I'd say the functional analysis version of calculus would be linear algebra and explicit solution of simple PDEs. But the analogy is rather loose.

Comment: Math is about proving theorem ...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the "calculus side" of functional analysis is... linear algebra. Functional analysis deals with vector spaces endowed with a topology (normed spaces, topological vector spaces), and the most elementary example of such spaces are finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Linear operators on finite-dimensional spaces are represented by matrices, spectral theory is the elementary theory of diagonalization of various kinds of matrices.

Comment: I think in general the people could agree with me if i say that calculus uses the theorems of analysis, so basically to have a good undestanding of calculus one should study analysis in depth. As example analysis provide a bunch of results for existence, while calculus provide tools for computing such result. So whether functional analysis say (inifinite dimensional space) "this operator is diagonalizable" which theory says "the computation is done in such way"? (if there exists of course).

Comment: In that sense there is no direct analog. In so many cases you cannot actually compute. For instance, the most celebrated result of functional analysis, namely the Hahn-Banach theorem, is proved by the axiom of choice. Linear functional analysis is a really abstract branch of mathematics. You can use it to solve partial differential equations, but you will never find a recipe to find explicit general solutions.

Comment: Even if i guess i know the answer... what do you mean when you say "you can use it to solve partial differential equations"?

Comment: I was thinking of variation of variational methods in Hilbert spaces, of semi group methods for parabolic equations, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In the same way that calculus was *invented* for computations in basic physics (kinematics, etc), and analysis was a rigorization of the heuristics, I think much of functional analysis was a rigorization of fancier computations in more modern physics, especially quantum theory.

Even before that, around 1900 rigorous treatment (such as it was) of ODEs and PDEs went by way of integral equations, which were easier to be confident of, as *bounded* operators.

In the 1920s, the basic models of operators $P,Q$ on a Hilbert space, with $PQ-QP=1$, could not possibly be correct with *bounded* operators. This did not necessarily deter physicists, but was a bit unnerving for mathematicians. Stone's and von Neumann's ~1930 rigorous treatment of unbounded operators on Hilbert spaces was visibly motivated by this.

Similarly, Heaviside's, and even more so Dirac's, use of "generalized functions" certainly was a big motivation in L. Schwartz' conception of "distributions", their Fourier transforms, and so on, to rigorize the wonderful heuristics that were so fruitful in physics.

(Similarly, many aspects of PDE are obviously motivated by physical problems: Navier-Stokes equation...)